# Update database schema in Entity Framework through Code

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity

Is it possible to update the entity data modal with the database through Vb.NET or C# code.

Comment: Your question title & detail conflict - Your asking if you can update the database schema via the EF and then asking is it possible to update the data model with the database. Which is it you need to know?

Comment: This is very poor and ambiguous question.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider `EF Code First`

Please see this walkthrough to get a kick start: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/05/ef-code-first-and-data-scaffolding-with-the-asp-net-mvc-3-tools-update.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Updating database schema using Code First unfortunately not supported. as per my knowledge. 
i was in a same situation once, 
this blog may help you

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/10/22/code-first-database-evolution-aka-migrations.aspx

and of course this

[Updating database schema with Entity Framework Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656604/updating-database-schema-with-entity-framework-code-first/)